# Laravel json response returns encrypted data

Tags: laravel, laravel-encryption

I'm using an Encryptable trait to encrypt my data for the a Room model.

RoomController *(/rooms)* returns the decrypted data but ApiRoomController *(/api/rooms)* does not.
How could I make it returns the decrypted data?

**Encryptable Trait**

```php
trait Encryptable
{
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        $value = parent::getAttribute($key);
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable) && $value !== '' && $value !== null ) {
            $value = Crypt::decrypt($value);
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, $this->encryptable)) {
            $value = Crypt::encrypt($value);
        }

        return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

**RoomController index function**

```php
public function index()
{
    $rooms = Room::select('id', 'name')->get()->sortBy('name')->values()->all();

    return view('rooms.index')->withRooms($rooms);
}
```

**ApiRoomController index function**

```php
public function index()
{
    $rooms = Room::select('id', 'name')->get()->sortBy('name')->values()->all();

    return response()->json($rooms);
}
```

Comment: Off topic but `$value !== '' && $value !== null` can be replaced with `!empty($value)` :) Also using this trait, would like to know the answer! +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources):

```
php artisan make:resource Rooms --collection
```

Then in your `app/Http/Resources/Rooms.php` file:

```php
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id'   => $this->id,
        'name' => $this->name,
        // more fields here
    ];
}
```

Then in your `ApiRoomController.php` file:

```php
use App\Http\Resources\Rooms;


public function index()
{
    $rooms = Room::select('id', 'name')->get()->sortBy('name')->values()->all();

    return Rooms::collection($rooms);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like @emotality came up with a good solution for this already...

However, the reason for this not working as you expected is because the underlying Model's `toArray()` / `toJson()` methods do not call the `getAttribute()` method in your trait.

This is important because the `response()->json()` method maps the given collection and calls the `toJson()` method on each model in order to prepare it for a response.

Therefore, you can also solve this by overwriting the `toArray` method in your model.

```
class Room extends Model
{
    use Encryptable;

    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            'id'   => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            // ...
        ];
    }
}
```